# MySQL with compress row format: Error Code: 1709. Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, owncloud, nextcloud

I'm trying to setup ownCloud with AWS Aurora MySQL 5.7 database but I get:
`Error Code: 1709. Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.`

Here are my queries:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE owncloud CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
CREATE TABLE owncloud.oc_mimetypes (
  `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `mimetype` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX mimetype_id_index (`mimetype`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

If I remove `ROW_FORMAT` option, it works fine.

Here my server config:

```
mysql> show variables like "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| aurora_version          | 2.03.1                       |
| innodb_version          | 5.7.12                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2        |
| version                 | 5.7.12                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+

mysql> show global variables like 'innodb_lar%';
+---------------------+-------+
| Variable_name       | Value |
+---------------------+-------+
| innodb_large_prefix | ON    |
+---------------------+-------+

mysql> show global variables like 'innodb_file%';
+--------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name            | Value     |
+--------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_file_format       | Barracuda |
| innodb_file_format_check | ON        |
| innodb_file_format_max   | Barracuda |
| innodb_file_per_table    | ON        |
+--------------------------+-----------+
```

Any idea?

Comment: *"Any idea?"* Yes make smaller indexes, remove ROW_FORMAT (like you already said).. use a other COLLATE as utf8mb4_bin uses 4 bytes as iam pretty a mimetype does not need to use utf8 using ascii or latin1 should also be fine..

Comment: I can't change this as ownCloud creates its schema on installation... See https://doc.owncloud.com/server/admin_manual/configuration/database/linux_database_configuration.html#configuring-a-mysql-or-mariadb-database